# Python Gtk3 : widget type

Tags: gtk, gtk3, pygobject

I'm a newbie in pyGobject (Gtk3). I'm trying to build my GUI, but I couldn't identify the highlighted areas showing in the picture below.

[image]

What is the name of that widget?

Comment: Please do not use irrelevant tags, such as `pygtk`, on your questions. It misleads those who follow those tags.

Answer (score 0):

The name of that widget is a [GtkTreeView](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeView.html). You have to give it a [GtkTreeModel](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeModel.html) containing your data.